# Sudzc ObjC code with ARC broken

Tags: objective-c, web-services, sudzc

I'm using Sudzc to create my WebService proxy classes for an iOS app.
The project is configured for ARC so i'm using the ARC Sudzc profile.

The problem being, as soon as I download the generated code. If I open up the example Xcode project. It always has a number of errors in SoapObject.m which is obviously part of a redistributed library.

An odd one being:
Cannot find interface declaration for 'SoapObject' when the header file is right there and the Assistant pulls it up straight away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horrifically Easy solution.
Must be developing with my eyes closed.

It appears there is a glitch with Sudzc's ARC code gen that misses 2 import statements.

Just stuck:

```
#import "Soap.h"
#import "SoapObject.h"
```

Above the implementation in SoapObject.m
Sorted.